# removing add to cart button on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have got a **Rental** category that I want to show price only, not allowing people to add to cart. (both on list view and details view). How can I do it on **Magento 2**?

P.S I have other categories as well that need to work as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add an attribute ex. IsRental (Yes/No) to category and save the attribute value all rental categories.

than after you can override `Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox` function `_toHtml`

in this you can just check attribute IsRental of current category from registry and return blank else return `parent::_toHtml()`